# Alignment (left, center, right) in a complex table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn, multirow, alignment

I'm encountering issues creating a complex table (i.e. using the `multirow` package). I'm new to creating (complex) tables and I have trouble aligning the content of the cells as I would like.

Here's is the table I would like to get (the red frames are the alignment I'd like to have):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setcellgapes{7.5pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7.5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7.5pt}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\form}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{40pt}
                    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{25pt}
                    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{120pt}
                    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{120pt}
                    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{120pt}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\form{Discriminant}} & $\Delta = b^2-4ac > 0$ & $\Delta = b^2-4ac = 0$ & $\Delta = b^2-4ac < 0$\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\form{Solutions}} & \shortstack{\form{2 racines simples}\\ $x = x_1 = \mathlarger{\frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}}$\\ ou\\ $x = x_2 = \mathlarger{\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}}$} & \shortstack{\form{Une racine double}\\ $x = x_0 = -\mathlarger{\frac{b}{2a}}$} & \form{Pas de solutions dans} $\mathbb{R}$\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\form{Forme factorisée}} & $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ & $a(x-x_0)^2$ & \form{Pas de forme factorisée dans} $\mathbb{R}$\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{\form{Graphe}} & $a > 0$ & \begin{tikzpicture}
                                                        \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                        \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                        \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                        \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {\zoom*2*\x*\x-.3});
                                                        \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X1}];
                                                        \path [name intersections={of=right and P, by=X2}];
                                                        \fill [black] (X1) circle (0.05) node [xshift=-5, yshift=-5]{$x_1$};
                                                        \fill [black] (X2) circle (0.05) node [xshift=5, yshift=-5]{$x_2$};
                                                    \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                    & \begin{tikzpicture}
                                                        \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                        \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                        \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                        \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {\zoom*2*\x*\x});
                                                        \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X0}];
                                                        \fill [black] (X0) circle (0.05) node [yshift=-6]{$x_0$};
                                                    \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                    & \begin{tikzpicture}
                                                        \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                        \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                        \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                        \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {\zoom*2*\x*\x+.3});
                                                    \end{tikzpicture}\\
                                                    \cline{2-5}
                                    & $a < 0$ & \begin{tikzpicture}
                                                    \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                    \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                    \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                    \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {-\zoom*2*\x*\x+.3});
                                                    \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X1}];
                                                    \path [name intersections={of=right and P, by=X2}];
                                                    \fill [black] (X1) circle (0.05) node [xshift=-5, yshift=5]{$x_1$};
                                                    \fill [black] (X2) circle (0.05) node [xshift=5, yshift=5]{$x_2$};
                                                \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                & \begin{tikzpicture}
                                                    \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                    \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                    \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                    \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {-\zoom*2*\x*\x});
                                                    \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X0}];
                                                    \fill [black] (X0) circle (0.05) node [yshift=6]{$x_0$};
                                                \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                & \begin{tikzpicture}
                                                    \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                    \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                    \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                    \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {-\zoom*2*\x*\x-.3});
                                                \end{tikzpicture}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{\form{Signe}} & $a > 0$ & ~ & ~ & ~\\\cline{2-5} & $a < 0$ & ~ & ~ & ~\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{\form{Variations}} & $a > 0$ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{~}\\\cline{2-5} & $a < 0$ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{~}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}{}
    \label{tab:recap}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

More broadly I don't quite understand how LaTeX handles alignments in an array/a table, and if possible I'd like to know a little bit about it.

Thanks!

Comment: please post as a single test document (just using packages needed for the example) not as disconnected fragments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your problems came from `\shortstack`, which was placing the baseline at the bottom.  I replaced it with `\parbox`, at which point you no longer needed p columns.

`Tikzpicture` normally places the baseline at the bottom, but that can be adjusted using the `[baseline=(...)]` option.

Finally there is `\multirow`, which is being confused by makecell and possibly setspace..  The best solution is to replace `\multirow` with `\raisebox` and calculate or guess how far to move the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}% need more space
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setcellgapes{7.5pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7.5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7.5pt}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\form}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\form{Discriminant}} & $\Delta = b^2-4ac > 0$ & $\Delta = b^2-4ac = 0$ & $\Delta = b^2-4ac < 0$\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\form{Solutions}} 
        & \parbox[c]{120pt}{\centering \form{2 racines simples}\\ $x = x_1 = \mathlarger{\frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}}$\\ ou\\ $x = x_2 = \mathlarger{\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}}$} 
        & \parbox[c]{120pt}{\centering \form{Une racine double}\\ $x = x_0 = -\mathlarger{\frac{b}{2a}}$} & \form{Pas de solutions dans} $\mathbb{R}$ \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\form{Forme factorisée}} & $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ & $a(x-x_0)^2$ 
        & \parbox[c]{120pt}{\form{Pas de forme factorisée dans} $\mathbb{R}$}\\
        \hline
        \raisebox{-40pt}[0pt][0pt]{\form{Graphe}} & $a > 0$ & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                                                        \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                        \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                        \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                        \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {\zoom*2*\x*\x-.3});
                                                        \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X1}];
                                                        \path [name intersections={of=right and P, by=X2}];
                                                        \fill [black] (X1) circle (0.05) node [xshift=-5, yshift=-5]{$x_1$};
                                                        \fill [black] (X2) circle (0.05) node [xshift=5, yshift=-5]{$x_2$};
                                                    \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                    & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                                                        \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                        \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                        \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                        \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {\zoom*2*\x*\x});
                                                        \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X0}];
                                                        \fill [black] (X0) circle (0.05) node [yshift=-6]{$x_0$};
                                                    \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                    & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                                                        \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                        \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                        \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                        \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {\zoom*2*\x*\x+.3});
                                                    \end{tikzpicture}\\
                                                    \cline{2-5}
                                    & $a < 0$ & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                                                    \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                    \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                    \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                    \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {-\zoom*2*\x*\x+.3});
                                                    \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X1}];
                                                    \path [name intersections={of=right and P, by=X2}];
                                                    \fill [black] (X1) circle (0.05) node [xshift=-5, yshift=5]{$x_1$};
                                                    \fill [black] (X2) circle (0.05) node [xshift=5, yshift=5]{$x_2$};
                                                \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                                                    \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                    \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                    \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                    \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {-\zoom*2*\x*\x});
                                                    \path [name intersections={of=left and P, by=X0}];
                                                    \fill [black] (X0) circle (0.05) node [yshift=6]{$x_0$};
                                                \end{tikzpicture} 
                                                & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                                                    \def\zoom{0.6}
                                                    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
                                                    \draw [name path=left] ({-\zoom*2},0)--(O);
                                                    \draw [->, name path=right] (O)--({\zoom*2},0);
                                                    \draw [thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, smooth, variable=\x, name path=P] plot (\x, {-\zoom*2*\x*\x-.3});
                                                \end{tikzpicture}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{\form{Signe}} & $a > 0$ & ~ & ~ & ~\\\cline{2-5} & $a < 0$ & ~ & ~ & ~\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}*{\form{Variations}} & $a > 0$ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{~}\\\cline{2-5} & $a < 0$ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{~}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}{}
    \label{tab:recap}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With use of `tabularx` table environment, `tikzse` for all pictures styles settings, more consistent drawing of diagrams and use `multirow` environments for vertical centering of cells contents (where is to my taste sensible) in the first two columns, The MWE with your table can be noticeably simplified and shortened:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% need more space NOT ANYMORE
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                intersections}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
%\usepackage{setspace} % not used in this MWE
%\usepackage{relsize}  % not used in this MWE
%\usepackage{sectsty}  % not used in this MWE
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{2}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{|c|}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{2}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand{\form}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}
%\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Récapitulation}
\label{tab:recap}
    \tikzset{dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
             arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 2]}},
     every label/.style = {label distance=1pt, inner sep=0pt},
          every picture = {baseline=(current bounding box.center)}
             }
\setcellgapes{7.5pt}
\makegapedcells
%\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|C|C|C|}
    \Xhline{1pt}
\mcc{\form{Discriminant}} 
    &   $\Delta = b^2-4ac > 0$ 
        &   $\Delta = b^2-4ac = 0$ 
            &   $\Delta = b^2-4ac < 0$                          \\
    \hline
\mcc{\form{Solutions}}
        &   \form{2 racines simples}\newline
            $\begin{aligned}
            x & = x_1 = \dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}    \\
            \mbox{ou}                                   \\
            x & = x_2 = \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
            \end{aligned}$
            &   \form{Une racine double}\newline
                $x = x_0 = -\dfrac{b}{2a}$ 
                &   \form{Pas de solutions dans} $\mathbb{R}$   \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\mcc{\multirow{2}{*}{\form{Forme factorisée}} }
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{$a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ }
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{$a(x-x_0)^2$ }
            &   \form{Pas de forme factorisée dans} $\mathbb{R}$\\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\multirow{3.4}{*}{\form{Graphe}}
    &   \multirow{-5}{*}{$a > 0$}
        &   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[arr, name path=A] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, name path=C] plot (\x,{\x*\x - 0.3});
            \path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={a,b}}]
                node [dot,label=below left: $x_1$] at (a) {}
                node [dot,label=below right:$x_2$] at (b) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[arr, name path=A] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, name path=C] plot (\x,\x*\x);
            \path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={a}}]
                node [dot,label=below: $x_0$] at (a) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[arr] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick, domain=-1.2:1.2] plot (\x,{\x*\x+0.3});
            \end{tikzpicture}                                   \\
    \cline{2-5}
    &   \multirow{-5}{*}{$a < 0$}
        &   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[arr, name path=A] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, name path=C] plot (\x,{-\x*\x + 0.3});
            \path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={a,b}}]
                node [dot,label=above left: $x_1$] at (a) {}
                node [dot,label=above right:$x_2$] at (b) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[arr, name path=A] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick, domain=-1.2:1.2, name path=C] plot (\x,-\x*\x);
            \path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={a}}]
                node [dot,label=$x_0$] at (a) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            &   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[arr] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick, domain=-1.2:1.2] plot (\x,{-\x*\x-0.3});
            \end{tikzpicture}                                   \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\multirow{3.4}*{\form{Signe}} 
    &   $a > 0$     & ~ & ~ & ~                                 \\
    \cline{2-5} 
    & $a < 0$       & ~ & ~ & ~                                 \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\multirow{3.2}*{\form{Variations}} 
    & $a > 0$ & \mc[3] {~}                                     \\
    \cline{2-5} 
    & $a < 0$ & \mc[3] {~}                                     \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]